# Django ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible'

Tags: python, django

I'm building a website and I was trying to create a custom user-to-user messaging system so I installed [django-messages](https://github.com/arneb/django-messages) and maybe a few other things, and suddenly when I tried to run my server I get the following error :

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django_messages\models.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (C:\Users\mertz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py)
```

It sounds like chinese to me, I don't understand a single line of this error, can someone help me ?
I've made a few researchs, it looks like it's related to a package name `six` but I was not able to find a solution. I can provide you my code if it's needed but I don't know which file you need so feel free to ask for a file in the comments and I will edit my post accordingly.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What happens if you enter the django shell and type `from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible`?

Comment: I get exactly the same error ```ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' ```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are using Django 3, where all [the Python 2 compatibility APIs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/#removed-private-python-2-compatibility-apis) that used to be bundled with Django were removed. `django-messages` still depends on these, and is trying and failing to import them.

You either need to downgrade to Django 2.2, or wait for `django-messages` to be updated for Django 3 support.

This applies for any library in which you get such errors - it means the library is not compatible yet with Django 3.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer ! But if I downgrade my version of Django, there is a probability that my website won't work anymore since I may be using some tools from Django 3 right ?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean. If you downgrade, you just need to make sure your code works with Django 2.2, and not any features that are only available in Django 3?

Comment: I solved the problem, I didn't downgrade Django and I built my own messaging system without using django-messages